# Expanding UIView -Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm working on an i-phone app that when you press a button a UITableView drops down. I want to push/animate the objects that are underneath the button so that they are underneath the tableview.

For each label/textfield that needs to be moved down would I need something like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, 70);
```

Any examples would be helpful.

Comment: you got it right. you just miss the [UIView commitAnimations] block at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you missed `commitAnimations` for the view.

Answer (score 5):

In iPhone OS 4.0 and later, [block-based animation methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131) are recommended by Apple such as

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations
```

for eg.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                     self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, 70);                     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there will be a `UITableView` that come from above to **self.view** and you wanted to move down all the elements in **self.view**, except the `UITableView`.

How about putting all the elements in **self.view** to a container view what have the same size as **self.view**? And then you can animate all the UI elements with one move

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];    
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];    
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.3];    
self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, 70);    
[UIView commitAnimations];
```